# Mensaje no traducido al español tras haberlo estado en el pasado

Tags: bug, traducciones

Al ir a revisar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130398/) que estaba en la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad, me encuentro que el mensaje que se da como razón de eliminación recomendada al seleccionar "Es un comentario de agradecimiento" está en inglés:

> “Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful.”

Estoy seguro de que antes no era así, así que en algún momento se ha vuelto al inglés.

La pregunta no trata sobre la traducción del texto como sugiere @Flxtr, sino sobre un texto que **ya estaba traducido al español**, y que por alguna razón esta traducción se ha revertido al inglés.

Edit:

Creo que puede pasar lo mismo en las colas de revisión. Ahora no estoy seguro pero juraría que esto estaba traducido (tampoco lo encuentro en el post de traducciones):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto sucede en todas las colas.

Comment: Parece que algunos mensajes que habían sido traducidos se han vuelto a poner en inglés. Vamos a ver con @JuanM a ver si el puede ayudar.

Comment: @Flxtr si, conozco el post. El problema aquí es que se trata de un texto que ya estaba traducido, y por alguna razón a vuelto a estar en inglés.

Comment: Hay que traducirlos de vuelta muchachos.. :( ver: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42241963#42241963

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: Hay que traducirlos de vuelta :(

Las traducciones son básicamente un diccionario de "texto en inglés" => "texto en español". Lo que pasó es que los amigos de Q&A cambiaron los textos en inglés, y eso hace que las traducciones anteriores queden obsoletas (porque la búsqueda se hace con el nuevo texto en inglés).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71585/discussion-between-g3rv4-and-fedorqui).