# Grupo de Traducción. ¿Te interesa?

Tags: discusión, traducciones

He notado, al igual que ustedes, que existen cadenas todavía no traducidas en nuestro sitio. También existen artículos del centro de ayuda que faltan traducir al español. Esto es algo que necesitamos corregir. Me gustaría proponer la siguiente idea - ¿qué tal si formamos un grupo de traductores cuyos compromisos sean el encontrar y traducir estas cadenas?  Los usuarios que nos están ayudando en Transifex han hecho un buen trabajo pero falta el explorar este sitio y el corregir cadenas que no existen en Transifex. Esta es la razón por la que todavía tenemos palabras en inglés escondidas por ahí.

Si la traducción es algo que te interesa, por favor considera unirte a este proyecto.  Tengo planeado el tener una junta con todos los interesados ya sea por chat o hangout para explicar en más detalle lo que se va a necesitar.  Si te gustar la idea, déjanos una respuesta para poder contactarte para el segundo paso.  El dejar una respuesta no indica que uno tiene que ser parte del equipo final - solamente que existe interés y se busca más información.

Dejaré este post abierto por 7 días y regresaré para contactar a los interesados. ¡Espero que se animen!

---

**Actualización:**

Hemos llegado a los 7 días y les agradezco su entusiasmo e interés.  Lo que toca ahora es la planeación de este proyecto.  Tengo preguntas pendientes que necesito contestar y también cosas que quiero discutir con ustedes.

La reunión tomará lugar este:

> jueves, 25 de enero a las 4pm GMT

.  Habrá una sala de chat para la discusión la cual pondré aquí. (falta crear la sala)

Para discutir y plantear sus preguntas - [**pásenle por aquí para enviármelas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3071/grupo-de-traducci%C3%B3n-la-charla).

---

**Si no pudiste participar en La Charla y el chat te parece difícil de seguir, lee [Grupo de Traducción - Resumen de la charla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3093/65)**

Comment: \o/ una vez que tengamos la lista de interesados, vamos a definir un proceso que nos sirva a todos y que sea lo más eficiente posible :) así que no sabemos bien cómo va a funcionar (ya que la idea es definirlo por consenso)

Comment: Contad conmigo.

Comment: Interesado en colaborar.

Comment: Colaborador listo para trabajar -->

Comment: Estoy interesado

Comment: +1 Me parece una idea realmente buena. Gracias!!

Comment: Sugiero bloquear este hilo a nuevas respuestas y ediciones pues ya pasó el plazo indicado y se movió la conversación a [Grupo de Traducción - La charla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3071/65)

Answer (score 7):

Entiendo que esta es una propuesta para agilizar un poco el trabajo en Transifex, coordinarlo mejor y sumar voluntarios. Desde ya, estoy más que dispuesto a ayudar y creo que es una buena forma de retribución para que, quien quiera agradecer a la comunidad de SOes, tenga una herramienta para contribuir... Quería cuestionar algunos puntos primero.

---

Me preocupa un poco seguir dedicando horas de esfuerzo de toda la comunidad para atacar diferentes soluciones de `Y` sin resolver realmente a `X`. <sup><sup>(referencia a ["problema XY"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/304899))</sup></sup>
Es decir, sin resolver el problema de raíz.

Con cada release que modifica el texto en SO perdemos la traducción actual. Entonces, caemos siempre en la misma trampa: dedicar tiempo y esfuerzo en cada traducción para textos que eventualmente vuelven a estar en inglés y, muchos de éstos están algo *ocultos* en la interfaz, por lo que puede pasar bastante tiempo hasta que volvemos a identificarlos y vemos que [hay que traducirlos de nuevo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3033/127). Terminamos arrastrándonos por detrás del problema en un ciclo sin fin.

Quiero aclarar que lo digo desde la perspectiva de alguien que le dedicó *muchísimo* tiempo a proponer traducciones (en publicaciones en Meta exclusivamente) y a quien le dolía la vista cada vez que reportaba un comentario y seguía viendo el texto en inglés (texto que además con cada cambio nos perjudica las métricas), y a quien le duele en el alma leer `Search…` allá arriba en la barra de búsqueda.

La verdad es que me molestó un poco haber leído en esta pregunta que:

> falta el explorar este sitio y el corregir cadenas que no existen en Transifex. Esta es la razón por la que todavía tenemos palabras en inglés escondidas por ahí.

cuando estoy bastante en desacuerdo. Creo que es evidente que lo que falta no es *explorar*, sino que falta una solución integral, y que estamos emparchando a mano este problema... Y tampoco había tanto problema con "emparchar a mano", pero a eso teníamos que sumarle (1) los meses que pasaban hasta que [Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman) encontraba un rato libre para dedicarle, (2) la cantidad de pings molestos que le dejábamos -no precisamente en horario español- hasta que podía responder, (3) la falta de una respuesta oficial de cuál era el protocolo a seguir con esas propuestas de traducción, (4) o de sobre quién recaía esa responsabilidad, que asumo que era "*sobre nadie*", y lo peor de todo (5) ver que los cambios que tanto esfuerzo llevaron volvían a estar en inglés.

Sin embargo, luego de preguntar y repreguntar cómo encarar este tema, sin respuesta, me enteré (no acá sino en [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)) que no hay que "*buscar las palabras*" nuevas. Tenemos la lista de textos a los que le falta traducción en https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing.

Por otro lado, sigo sin entender por qué tardamos tanto en implementar [las propuestas de traducciones en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traducciones+-estado-completado+-estado-por-dise%C3%B1o). Comparemos exclusivamente con [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), un sitio que teóricamente tendría los mismos problemas que nosotros, pero normalmente los resuelven [en apenas un par de días](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o+status-pronto). ¿Qué es lo que estamos haciendo mal?

Todos estos fueron factores que, por lo menos a mí, me desanimaron para seguir proponiendo traducciones. No me gusta dedicar esfuerzo en vano.

Ahora bien, agradezco enormemente la predisposición de [g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) para [agilizar la revisión de Transifex](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42291661#42291661). Me pone muy contento haber leído que lo iba a hacer -¡capo total!. Claramente nos faltaba un empleado de SE que tome esta tarea para que esto funcione en SOes (a diferencia de casi cualquier otro sitio que tiene personas -generalmente varias- que pueden hacerlo). Creo que es un paso gigantesco hacia una solución a este problema.

Entonces, está genial esto de por fin ordenar el proceso de Transifex (sea como sea que salga), sumar a alguien que tiene acceso para aceptar las revisiones, y poder unir y coordinar el esfuerzo de la comunidad para la tarea. Hasta ahora Transifex fue siempre nuestro talón de Aquiles en cuanto a las traducciones. ¡Me alegro que esto se esté encarando por fin!

No obstante, creo que estamos pasando por alto problemas comunes que ya surgieron en otros sitios. No estamos aprovechando las lecciones aprendidas que tenemos a disposición. Entre ellas:

1. ¿Por qué estamos haciendo una publicación para sumar voluntarios que tengan que responder acá para entrar? Esto me parece que tiende a desanimar a algunos. Hagamos un FAQ para que cualquiera, en cualquier momento, pueda sumarse, sin tener que exponerse en una publicación en Meta. Creo que la misma interfaz de Transifex te permite solicitar el ingreso (sin tener que publicar en Meta o enviar mails). Podemos tomar como ejemplo a [*Mil tradutores são melhores que um*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2705/53463).
2. ¿Qué solución se le puede encontrar para reconocer en Transifex a todos [los textos no implementados aún en el sitio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38733269#38733269) (que incluso pueden nunca ser implementados)?
3. Si bien la lista de "[*Falta traducción*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)" ofrece enlaces a donde se encuentran los textos, ¿se implementó o se piensa implementar alguna herramienta dentro de Transifex para mostrar el contexto de cada término?
4. ¿Podemos tener [un bot](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4240/53463) que nos avise de cada nuevo texto en Transifex?
5. El cuello de botella suele ser la aprobación de los términos (sólo mods). ¿Tenemos alguna alternativa para evitar este problema? Y si no existe, ¿no es más alto el costo de oportunidad de seguir usando recursos de empleados de SE en todos los sitios internacionales versus el desarrollo de algún tipo de revisión por los usuarios?
6. ¿Vamos a solucionar Transifex pero no los textos hardcoddeados que no estén en Transifex? ¿Cómo hacemos para documentar un procedimiento oficial para traducir estos textos?

Creo que estas son cuestiones para las cuales querría tener una respuesta oficial (incluso cuando es negativa) antes de dedicarle tiempo a una traducción.

Comment: Concuerdo totalmente.. necesitamos una solucion de raiz.. mas alla de que unirse a transifex es una pavada (ya lo hice y ya me aprobaron, no se quien) no se si vale la pena tener un equipo.. o solo promocionarlo, decir como es el metodo.. y aceptar traducciones.. en el peor de los casos, como nuestro español es levemente diferente.. levantar un chat sobre traducciones para analizar cada caso (si no recuerdo mal en la beta se hacia algo asi con el excel)

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba... aprete sobre el link que paso mariano.. despues presione sobre la key donde figura el texto sin traducir.. y me llevo directamente al transifex donde me aparecio el texto sin traducir.. ya traduje search, ahora abria que probar si ese push cambia la bendita barra de tareas!

Comment: Estoy muy de acuerdo con lo que comentas. Además, ¡gran descubrimiento el de https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing!

Comment: Comparto por lo demás tu sensación de cansamiento por estar sugiriendo traducciones constantemente y sentirte un poco mal por hacer pings constantes a Konamiman para que las añada. Mantenemos una lista de respuestas bien ordenaditas, lo que hace que para un empleado de SO atajar la lista de pendientes sea trivial dedicándole unos minutos a la semana.

Comment: Ahora, sí es necesario que internamente SO defina cómo operar para que no sea responsabilidad de los usuarios tener que darse cuenta de qué es lo que está pendiente de traducir o qué se rompe cada vez que hay cambios.

Comment: @fedorqui al menos ahora hemos encontrado un sistema para agilizar las cosas. Ya algunos mas tenemos acceso a Transifex, y teniendo a g3rv4 comprometido con aprobar las traducciones, yo creo que en poco tiempo tendremos todo traducido.:)

Comment: Por cierto @Mariano, lo de https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing es un descubrimiento. Con ello se agiliza muchisimo el proceso!

Comment: @Pikoh ¡por supuesto! Lo que no me gusta es el paso atrás: antes reportábamos textos y Konamiman los metía y, con sus poderes de empleado, ya estaban actualizados. Ahora tenemos que sugerirlos nosotros, indicarlo en un google docs, ver si g3rv4 lo ha actualizado y luego marcarlo como hecho en la respuesta de Meta. Mola porque vuelve a poderse añadir traducciones, pero es algo tedioso ¡A ver si se define un proceso ágil y fácil! Lo suyo sería dar permisos de aprobar a usuarios de confianza tipo moderadores.

Comment: @fedorqui bueno, vamos a ver como va la cosa, aunque no me parece mal que hubiera alguien mas con poderes de revisor a parte de g3rv4.

Comment: @Pikoh no dejo de verle el lado positivo. Yo también creo que así lo solucionamos en poco tiempo. Pero no pierdas de vista el punto: hace aproximadamente 1 año la gran mayoría de los textos "visibles" ya estaban en español! Cómo dije al principio, creo que es encontrar un mecanismo para atacar a Y sin resolver X... Y sí, la lista de Falta Traducción está genial, pero pensá que la descubrí en [PT.so], sin que haya un canal de comunicación para enterarnos directamente acá.

Comment: @Mariano estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Yo ya expresé mi sorpresa en algunos comentarios (que deben haber sido eliminados ya que no les encuentro) [en la pregunta que hice](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3031/15301) sobre lo extraño que se me hacía tener que volver a traducir textos que ya había sido traducidos. Pero al menos, ahora tenemos algo para avanzar,ya que el post de sugerencias de traducciones llevaba parado mucho tiempo.

Comment: @Mariano al menos, las dos cosas que yo decía en mi pregunta ya vuelven a estar en español, asi que el proceso va funcionando :)

Comment: @Mariano 6) Ayer mandé un PR para traducir la página de la badge "Not a Robot". A medida que pueda (fuera del horario de trabajo) las voy haciendo localizables.

Comment: respecto a los artículos de ayuda... voy a ver si puedo darme acceso sin hacerme mod

Comment: @g3rv4 buenísimo. Y está genial lo que estás haciendo! Aplaudo tu dedicación. No quiero sonar tan negativo, pero en serio falta aclarar cómo se hace cuando a vos se te vayan las ganas. Si tengo que sacar conclusiones, la respuesta al punto (6) sería "No existe un procedimiento. No hay recursos asignados para la i18n de textos. La única vía es que un empleado de SO te lo haga como favor. *Happy hunting*"... ¿Se entiende el punto? Sí es así, oka, pero me gustaría que esté claro y no estemos adivinando cómo se hace en cada etapa.

Comment: @Mariano entiendo perfecto. Eso es algo que podemos charlar en la reunión / hangout que hagamos para coordinar.

Comment: Los no angloparlantes somos ciudadanos de segunda.

Comment: @Jose entiendo de dónde se origina tu comentario, pero estoy convencido de lo contrario. [PT.so] y [ru.so] funcionan muy bien en estas cosas. Si es algo, yo creo que las falencias están primero en la comunidad de usuarios antes que a en la empresa o sus empleados.

Answer (score 4):

Me too! (En inglés para que veais que sé). :)

Comment: Como mola esta respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy interesado en participar

Answer (score 2):

Me interesa unirme al grupo de traducción.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy interesado en unirme al grupo de traduccion.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy interesado, la respuesta y la pregunta son muy largas pero supongo que es para ayudar a traducir el sitio

Answer (score 2):

Por aquí interesado y a la orden

Answer (score 1):

Me interesa unirme al grupo de traducción.

Answer (score 1):

Me interesa unirme al grupo de traducción!

Answer (score 1):

Me interesa unirme al grupo avisan para poder empezar

Answer (score 1):

me apunto, solo me avisan. espero ayudarlos a la mayor brevedad.

Answer (score 1):

En la medida de mis posibilidades cuenten conmigo.

Answer (score 0):

i'm new here but i'd like to translate some text if this can help the community.

Comment: Genial, pero ¿por qué en inglés?