# ¿Debería estar en español el mensaje que sale cuando editas una pregunta?

Tags: bug, traducciones

¿No debería estar en español el mensaje que sale cuando editas una pregunta?

Me sale en inglés:

> thanks for your edit...

Debería ser:

> gracias por tu edición...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Sí, todos los mensajes deberían estar en español. "Usualmente" estos casos se reportan en [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/65) por lo que no te extrañe que se marque como duplicado de dicha "pregunta".

Relacionado

- [Grupo de Traducción. ¿Te interesa?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3037/65)
- [Respuesta de Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3041/65) a la pregunta anterior.