# Grupo de Traducción - Resumen de la charla

Tags: soporte, traducciones, meta

Pues ya se llevó a cabo la charla anunciada en [Grupo de Traducción - La charla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3071/65)

¿Alguna alma caritativa que nos regale una lista concreta de acciones por hacer a los que nos manifestamos como interesados?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como en toda buena reunion, nadie se llevo tarea para hacer en el hogar.. con las siguientes excepciones:

- El proceso de traduccion tiene varios pasos que Gerv no explico concretamente. Ellos son:

  - Un desarrollador usa una cadena en una página
  - Al hacer commit, se hace un build de stage (el entorno de pruebas)
  - Como parte del build, se hace "push" de la cadena a Transifex
  - Un traductor la traduce
  - Un reviewer la aprueba
  - Un CM/dev hace "pull" de transifex a la base de datos
  - Un dev hace build de producción

Las partes que nos atañen a nosotros son: traducir, revisar, hacer el pull...

La parte de traducir es donde tenemos mas dudas, ya que vimos traducciones muy malas. Y ademas es donde tendriamos el cuello de botella (junto con aprobar) porque tenemos que ponernos de acuerdo como traducir y avisar que traducimos.

La plataforma de traduccion es Transifex, unirse es facil, y encontrar el proyecto de traduccion tambien, solo hay que esperar que Juan apruebe el usuario y cualquiera ya puede traducir.

Luego de traducir, hay que aprobar las cadenas. Eso implica que alguien "vuelva" a traducir (por ponerlo de alguna forma, ya que tiene que mirar la frase en ingles y la de español y darle el ok). Este proceso por ahora queda en manos de los moderadores, y de Juan y Gervasio (En realidad solo se van a encargar los moderadores, los otros solo tienen permiso).

Una vez hecho esto, hay que avisarle a Gervasio, quien se ofrecio mas que amablemente (ayudenme a comprarle alfajores) a hacer pull todas las veces que haga falta. Esto si le ahorramos el trabajo de revisar dijo que era simple, asi que mejor si se lo ahorramos.

Las otras tareas, no nos atañen a ninguno de nosotros.

En cuanto a cosas hardcodeadas que no estan en trasifex, tambien deberiamos avisarle a Gerv, que va a hacer el reclamo correspondiente para que esas cadenas empiezen a aparecer en transifex.

Muchas de las cadenas no tienen contexto, al parecer es muy complicado ponerles contexto, asi que se complica saber de donde salen. Vamos a necesitar estar muy atentos.

Si algo es urgente (ayer alguien tradujo chat a conversacion, y en todos los footer se leia conversacion) se le puede avisar a gerv, pero para casos puntuales y graves. (el boton close no es un caso grave).

Deberiamos tener un pre proceso de traducciones, se hablo de armar un bot que nos avise de textos nuevos, miramos la api para ver si se puede desarrollar algo contra eso, pero ya corre por parte de cada uno ver si sacamos algo en limpio de eso.

Para los textos en ingles que no encontramos en transi, se hablo de hacer una etiqueta [agregar-a-transifex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agregar-a-transifex) (ya se hizo) y asi Gerv puede ubicar dentro del codigo fuente el texto que no esta en transi, avisar donde corresponda y que hagan lo que haga falta para pasarlo.

Todavia tenemos que tener alguna clase de proceso por la cual alguien que traduzca algo, sea revisado por sus pares, pero transi por mas que permite hacer consultas puntuales (traducciones desde, hechas por tal usuario y varias cosas mas), son todas a mano. No hay otra forma de saberlo. Por eso quedamos en ver si podemos sacar algo en limpio de las apis.

A titulo personal, me gustaria tener algun sistema de pre aprobacion de dos capas, con usuarios de segunda (recien llegados, que no conozcamos), usuarios de primera (que sabemos que son confiables en las traducciones), revisores (que son los mods, pero deberian confiar en las traducciones de los de primera). El tema es como avisar. Yo sigo inclinandome por una ventana de chat limpia donde un usr avise que hizo modificaciones e ir a transi y revisar solo eso. porque post en meta me parece que van a hacer mucho ruido. o vamos a llenar meta con alguien que tradujo 3 palabras (algo muy valido, pero es mucha infraestructura para tan poco).

Si me olvide de algo, sirvan corregirme, o ponemos esto como wiki.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Tan pronto me sea posible leeré con detenimiento esto que a primera vista se ve muy completo.