# ¿Qué hacemos con un texto que aparece en el sitio en español, pero que en Transifex no aparece traducido?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-no-reproducido, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex, transifex

En [**nuestro perfil**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile):

> [image: Perfil]

tenemos el texto **en español**:

> visitado ### días, ### consecutivos.

En Transifex aparece en [930bf60fabb24d48556af3936c0aa41d](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/132606285?key=930bf60fabb24d48556af3936c0aa41d) sin **ninguna traducción**.

Recién lo traduje en Transifex, y me imagino que las toma de otro lado y tengo que solicitarles: ¿Podrían agregar la internacionalización de esas cadenas en la interfaz?

Comment: Aparece dos veces porque son distintos textos... uno dice "consecutive" y el otro "consecutively"... cambiaron el texto en el código (el que está hoy en día activo es "consecutive")

Comment: @g3rv4 ah, ja, no me había fijado en el detalle :-) -Igual recién los traduje yo a ambos, que estaban sin nada

Comment: ya están localizados en el código (y ya estaban [traducidos en la base de datos](https://gmc.uy/enLaDb.png)). Sospecho que, al igual que el otro texto que vimos hoy, al principio no se usaba el mismo proceso... y por lo tanto, tenemos cadenas traducidas en el sitio que aparecen sin review en transifex.

Comment: @g3rv4 entonces, para entender... se van a sobreescribir en la base, por lo que no hay que hacer nada... esperamos y aparecen? ... [no repro](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/cnr.png) y que quede como destino de otras duplicadas?

Comment: estas cadenas ya estaban localizadas, fueron traducidas en transifex pero *mi hipótesis* es que en tiempos antiguos, no era necesario el review para que fueran importadas. Como el proceso cambió, tu update tuvo que ser revisado (yo lo revisé) e importado (de ahí viene el screenshot que puse). En el próximo build vamos a ver los strings nuevos. No repro tiene sentido (no fue necesario agregar a transifex, porque ya estaba)

Comment: @g3rv4 Genial que aparezcan!... pero en cuanto a *tu hipótesis*: si en tiempos antiguos estaban en Transifex, yo esperaría que sigan estando en Transifex. Fijate que este no es el caso. Estas cadenas no tenían ningún historial, estaban vacías... ¿Será que metían los términos a mano en la base?

Comment: uh es cierto... ahí se fue mi hipótesis por el caño... no sé cómo llegaron a la base de datos entonces

Comment: nono, si sé algo que no puedo decir, puedo decir que sé algo y no lo puedo decir. En este caso, no sé algo y lo puedo decir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según los [comentarios de g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3107/i18n-de-visit%C3%B3-d%C3%ADas-consecutivos-en-el-perfil?noredirect=1#comment10789_3107), ya estaban traducidas en la base de datos de SO:

> [image: "Strings that we already have"]

Por algún motivo (que desconocemos), estas cadenas **no estaban** en Transifex, pero **ya se había realizado** la i18n dentro del código. Es decir, dejando que siga el proceso normal ([revisión, pull, build](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3096/127)), van a sobreescribir a las cadenas antiguas que estaban en la base de datos y se van a ver reflejadas en el sitio (en [tu perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile) en este caso).

En definitiva, no hay que solicitar que se agreguen a Transifex.
El procedimiento sería: **No hay que hacer nada**.

#### *No repro*

[image: No se pudo reproducir]