# Traduciendo el sitio... Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso

Tags: discusión, traducciones

### TL;DR

Probamos usar [traducir.win](https://traducir.win) para hacer traducciones en vez de Transifex. Si visitás el sitio, te podés loguear y sugerir traducciones para el sitio con tu cuenta de Stack Overflow en español.

Pasó el mes en el que propuse probar esta app. En este mes tuvimos:

- 1119 sugerencias de traducciones
- 962 sugerencias aprobadas (esas son... cadenas traducidas!)
- 44 usuarios registrados
- 101 commits al proyecto hechos por 4 personas
- 0 moderadores amenazando con convertirse en Liam Neeson

Yo diría, desde mi lugar bastante sesgado, que fue un éxito... por lo que, después del mes de prueba, y por acuerdo de todos, **traducir.win es la forma de traducir el sitio hasta que decidamos otra cosa** :D

### Historia

Como quienes siguen la novela de las traducciones ya saben, mantener el sitio en español traducido ha sido una experiencia un tanto... frustrante. Hace no mucho tuvimos "[la charla](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72224/conversation/grupo-de-traduccion-la-charla)" ([resumida acá](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3096/11272) por [gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi)) a partir de la que [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) definió [un proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3166/11272) que tenía sentido *siempre y cuando pudiésemos confiar en que lo que uno pone en Transifex queda en Transifex* *.

La verdad es que, por problemas en el código Stack Overflow que sincroniza las cadenas con Transifex, esto no pasaba... En un momento, [Álvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) amenazó [con convertirse en Liam Neeson](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43127870#43127870) si las cadenas que con tanto amor había aprobado volvían a aparecer sin aprobar. ¿Adivinen qué? 7 horas después [pasó exactamente eso](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43134715#43134715) (todavía no hemos recibido noticias de la prometida metamorfosis).

<sup>* Eso si no consideramos que Transifex no tiene forma de rechazar una sugerencia... queda como traducción sin aprobar para siempre.</sup>

### La aplicación

Seguimos charlando en el chat y viendo los problemas que la integración de Stack Overflow tiene con Transifex... pensando cómo podíamos resolver el problema sin usar recursos de la empresa (que en este momento los tiene enfocados en otras áreas) ¡hasta que [Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) sugirió [que lo hagamos nosotros](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43297975#43297975)! sin Transifex en absoluto.

Así que yo me pedí unos días en mi trabajo y, con las geniales ideas de Mariano + la sugerencia de gbianchi de un sistema de pre-aprobación de dos capas, construí [traducir.win](https://traducir.win) que es justamente eso: una aplicación para traducir el sitio sin usar transifex.

Las funcionalidades que tiene ahora son:

- Búsqueda de cadenas usando expresiones regulares (y otros filtros útiles).
- Log in con la cuenta de SOes. No hace falta registrarse en ningún lado, quienes tienen cuenta acá pueden loguearse en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win).
- Posibilidad de tener "trusted users" (usuarios de confianza) que pueden aprobar traducciones de usuarios normales para hacer más fácil el trabajo de los moderadores.
- Pull y push de Transifex cada 10 minutos (con lo que no es necesario que nadie entre a la interfaz de Transifex).

La aplicación tiene el backend en .NET Core y el frontend hecho con React, usando una base de datos SQL Server. El [código fuente está disponible acá](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) y la idea de largo plazo es que sea un proyecto desarrollado por la comunidad, ¡por lo que las contribuciones de todo tipo (¿tests? ¿hacer <strike>más lindo</strike> menos feo el código de react-router? ¿estadísticas? ¿un logo?) son muy bienvenidas!

### Los datos

La aplicación no guarda ningún dato privado y loguea todas las acciones de los usuarios (quién sugiere algo, quién aprueba o rechaza)... pero hoy en día no hay ninguna interfaz para ver esas cosas.

Por eso, configuré una instancia de [Redash](https://redash.io/) en [db.traducir.win](https://db.traducir.win) (el nombre de usuario es `db@traducir.win` y la contraseña es `letMeInPleeeease`). Si querés tu propio usuario (para que no te puedan borrar / editar las consultas) llená [este formulario](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf_1T7-oDK1x_hJ2rRAPvA0OYrps6HYFSqyvlLAQJ66Ml1qQg/viewform?usp=sf_link) y te mando un enlace al mail.

Por último, la base de datos se respalda dos veces por día en [db-backups.traducir.win](https://db-backups.traducir.win/) para que cualquiera la baje y la restaure en un servidor local.

### La propuesta

Con este (¿breve?) resumen, y viendo la situación en la que estamos, la propuesta actual es *probemos [traducir.win](https://traducir.win)* para manejar nuestras traducciones. Usemos el sistema un mes y decidamos si esto es mejor que lo que tenemos ahora.

Salgamos todos de Transifex (salvo quienes quieran ayudar a debugguear el sistema) y manejemos todo en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win). Designemos como usuarios de confianza a aquellos usuarios que tienen un historial de sugerencias aprobadas en el sistema.

Y, por último, la principal invitación es a construir en comunidad esta aplicación para resolver los problemas de esta comunidad.

Para que esto pase, [escribí un documento para configurar la solución de forma local](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/docs/DEV_ENVIRONMENT.md) y voy a hacer una sesión de live coding donde no voy a hacer live coding sino hablar un poco de la estructura de la aplicación, algunas decisiones técnicas y el proceso de deploy automático.

### La demo

[Hicimos un webcast con Juan M](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgFqnHVnIbA) mostrando cómo se usa la aplicación y qué problemas resuelve.

### Soporte

Por ahora estamos coordinando los esfuerzos en [la sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72224/hablemos-sobre-las-traducciones).

<sub>Por si no lo mencioné, la url de la aplicación es [traducir.win](https://traducir.win).</sub>

Comment: Esta es una excelente aportación a la comunidad y nos deja un ejemplo de lo que podemos hacer juntos. Gracias a Mariano y a gbianchi por sus recomendaciones y apoyo también. ¡Sigamos adelante! :D

Comment: Impresionante vuestra aportación, me parece muy util. Lo único...no es un poco contrasentido que una web para traducir cadenas del inglés al español...esté en inglés? :)

Comment: @Pikoh la idea es que si funciona bien, se pueda usar en otras comunidades... y además, quienes la usen **tienen** que entender inglés... si no, no pueden ayudar con las traducciones (ya que la premisa es que van a traducir *de inglés* a otro idioma)

Comment: @g3rv4 por supuesto, ya imaginé que la herramienta podría ser trasladada a otras comunidades, ya que dado el trabajo que habrá supuesto cuanta más utilidad tenga mejor. Simplemente, al ser al menos de momento un herramienta para [es.so]...pues hecho en falta que el lenguaje por defecto sea el español. Mas por coherencia ya que como bien dices, quien haga uso de ella debería entender el inglés. Es una humilde sugerencia.

Comment: @Pikoh entendido :D localizar una aplicación es un trabajo para nada menor, y dado que el 100% de los usuarios a los que apunta entiende inglés, no queda del todo claro que invertir tiempo en eso tenga mucho sentido ;)

Comment: Por supuesto, entiendo los costes de localizar la aplicación. De nuevo, felicitarte a ti y a todos los que han participado en su realización :)

Comment: @Pikoh podríamos proponer las traducciones de esta herramienta y que se pueda utilizar en otras comunidades, por ejemplo utilizando Transif... oh, wait! :D

Comment: @fedorqui exacto! no more pain pleaseeeeee

Comment: @fedorqui fair enough...fair enough XD

Comment: Mis respetos para el proyecto, se nota que la unión hace la fuerza :D en cualquier momento entro a jugar con ustedes en este proyecto, éxitos hermanos :D

Comment: Me gustaría participar completamente dentro de este proyecto, si aún no se tiene un logotipo definido me gustaría adentrarme en eso y crear varias opciones. Me gusta la manera en la que se organizan y piensan por el bien de la comunidad.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado eso sería FLOR de ayuda :) un logo lindo como para poner por ahí (si tiene un unicornio, entonces reemplazaría al emoji capaz?) y como favicon... GRACIAS!

Comment: @g3rv4 claro con mucho gusto, en cuanto tenga resultados por donde puedo hacerles llegar el logotipo para que lo miren y me den criticas constructivas.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado creá [un issue en github](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues)

Comment: @g3rv4 listo ya cree el issue.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado muy chulos!!

Comment: @g3rv4 el que sea mas de tu agrado me dices para pasarte el .png del logo y con el mismo unicornio que esta dentro de la O crear el favicon.

Comment: Muy buen aporte @g3rv4, lo estuve mirando y tiene muy buena pinta.

Comment: Hay algo que no me quedó muy claro. ¿La URL de la aplicación es [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/)? :P

Comment: @KacosPro si, [traducir.fail](https://traducir.fail) es para la gente masoquista

Comment: Jajaja! Espero poder colaborar en algún momento con el front end :)

Comment: He estado probando la web y va de maravilla, enhorabuena a todos los integrantes del proyecto **+1000** y muchas gracias por colaboraciones de este tipo, **la unión hace la fuerza** espero poder ayudar con unas cuantas traducciones!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sigamos con [traducir.win](https://traducir.win) :) es lo mejor que le pasó a las traducciones desde la invención del dulce de leche.

Comment: se compara con un panqueque de ddl.. ojo eh...

Comment: Creo que es hora de un post en [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/65) con ese slogan

Comment: Gracias a @g3rv4 y  todos los que colaboraron, excelente!

Comment: g3rv4: cualquier cosa que busco en https://es.traducir.win me da resultado vacío. ¿Será que hay algún problema?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' tenés algún link a una búsqueda? a mi me anda bien... si me pasás un link o la búsqueda me fijo

Comment: Oh, ahora ya me funciona, qué raro. Créeme que no me daba ningún resultado. Bueno, mejor así. Si vuelve a suceder, te paso más datos. Gracias!

Comment: te creo, sin dudas :) cuando pase, fijate si hay algo en https://es.traducir.win/errors

Comment: genial, tremendo proyecto montaste...