# Texto de ejemplo en Acerca de mí en perfil de usuario nuevo

Tags: discusión, traducciones

Al crear un usuario nuevo, luego de completar el registro si se va al perfil de usuario y luego a Editar perfil y configuración, el texto de ejemplo en Acerca de mí está en inglés:

> BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
>
> BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for penalcoders.example.org, an
>   awesome non-profit that will totally take your money at that link. My
>   kids are cuter than yours.
>
> FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in
>   Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
>
> "If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see
>   people helping."-Fred Rogers

En mi opinión no tiene sentido hacer una traducción pero tampoco se me ocurre algo interesante.

¿Alguna idea?

P.D. si alguno se anima a hacer la propuesta directamente en traducir.win, por favor avise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La verdad es que hoy me topé con esta cadena y me puse a traducirla sin haber visto esta pregunta. Mi sugerencia puede consultarse [aqui](https://traducir.win/string/2582) y reza lo siguiente:

> POR EL DÍA: Vaquera Ninja Cantante de Rock Alternativo en Veridian Dynamics.
>
> POR LA NOCHE: Escribo código y sobre derechos de código para
>   programadoreslegales.ejemplo.org, una increíble ONG que aceptará sin
>   duda tu dinero en ese enlace. Mis hijos son mas guapos que los tuyos.
>
> POR DIVERSIÓN: Bromas de C+, Curling, Pasatiempos Dominicales del
>   Periódico (¡con Rotulador Fluorescente!), Criador de Avestruces.
>
> "Cuando veía cosas dolorosas en las noticias, mi madre solía decirme:
>   ‘mira a los que ayudan, siempre encontrarás gente ayudando’."-Fred
>   Rogers

Por el momento, la sugerencia ha sido aprobada y aparecerá próximamente en el sitio (@g3rv4 podrá explicar mejor el período de tiempo que se tarda desde la aprobación hasta que aparece en el sitio).

Me he tomado la libertad de no hacer una traducción 1:1 ya que el original tiene ciertas referencias que probablemente no se entienden igual en el mundo hispano, pero por supuesto está sujeto a discusión y las sugerencias de todos.

**P.D. Importante:**

Aprovecho para recordar que, además de informar aquí de las cadenas que se detecte que están en ingles, todos los usuarios de StackOverflow en Español pueden realizar sugerencias de traducción en [traducir.win](http://traducir.win) buscando la cadena sin traducir. Si no se sabe como traducirla, o simplemente no se desea hacerlo, también es importante (y muy útil) marcar la cadena como urgente (*Mark as Urgent*) para que aparezca destacada para su traducción lo antes posible.

*Relacionado:* [Traduciendo el sitio... Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/15301)

Comment: Gracias. Había visto el botón de marcar como urgente pero no sabía de los criterios de cuándo debería usarse, así que había optado por no usarlo ¿Lo que estás diciendo es  que **siempre** que encontremos una cadena sin traducir debe marcarse como urgente?

Comment: @Rubén Si. Esa opción fue una sugerencia mia que puedes ver [aqui](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues/10) y viene motivada porque hay (había en realidad) mas de mil cadenas sin traducir,muchas de las cuales no aparecen en el sito. Para poder centrarnos en las que si, se puso esa opción de tal manera que los traductores se pueden centrar  en ellas :)

Comment: Ahora que lo veo, fue sugerencia mia en el chat, pero el que dió de alta el issue fue @g3rv4...se me llevó el mérito ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan detallada explicación :)

Comment: yo diría que "marcar como urgente" debería usarse cuando alguien ve una cadena en inglés en el sitio... es una forma de resaltar que es una cadena para la que **seguro** necesitamos traducción. Respecto al tiempo: Una vez que un reviewer aprueba una cadena en traducir.win, se hace push a transifex en los próximos 10 minutos. Una vez que pasa eso, es necesario que Juan o yo importemos MANUALMENTE (apretando un botón) las cadenas en la base de datos... y a partir de ahí, en el próximo build queda traducido acá. En el caso de esta cadena, estamos esperando un build.

Comment: @g3rv4 si,no se si no me expliqué bien. Me referia a eso, que "urgentes" son las cadenas que se detecten en el sitio

Comment: @Pikoh ahora que releí la respuesta y el comentario, si :D

Comment: Pues habíamos hablado de esto en el [chat de las traducciones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43982678#43982678) y tú mismo estuviste de acuerdo en que había que hacer una vesión propia y no una traducción. Supongo que lo olvidaste xD

Comment: Gracias por hacerme ser mas consciente de mi alzheimer en fase avanzada @blonfu XD

Comment: Criador**a** de avestruces. En cuanto a lo de "*C+*" no se a quién gritarle.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus no se por qué criadora. Si es por lo de "vaquera", entiendo que es una broma que no tiene por qué corresponderse con el género. En cuanto a lo de C+...mira que lo hemos revisado 2 personas y no nos hemos dado cuenta, mil disculpas :_(. Puedes entrar en el enlace a la sugerencia y añadir la tuya propia, solucionando los errores y añadiendo algo mas de cosecha propia si te parece :)

Comment: Si es vaquer**a**, será criador**a**. De todas maneras "[To groom](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/groom)" no es criar, es más correcta la traducción de [PAGANA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/71015/pagana?tab=profile). En cuanto a "*C+*" está así en el original, aunque me duela en el alma no tengo nadie de SOes a quien gritarle al respecto.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus como digo en mi respuesta, he intentado hacer una traducción que no fuera 1:1 ya que en el original hay "bromas inglesas" que tal vez no se entendieran bien. Por eso, pensé que quedaba mejor "criador". Como digo, esto solo ha sido un primer intento para que apareciera ya en español, pero está abierto a todas las sugerencias y modificaciones que se os ocurran :)

Comment: Yo haría algo totalmente distinto, no hay ni porque mantener eso de por el día, por la noche, etc. Pero es más fácil decirlo que hacerlo

Comment: @blonfu estas totalmente invitado a proponer algo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Encontré un usuario llamado *PAGANA* que puso la traducción en su perfil.

> https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/71015/pagana?tab=profile

También, un usuario llamado *[Rastalovely](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15817/rastalovely?tab=profile)*, tiene algo parecido.

El texto de *PAGANA* es el siguiente (lo corregí un poco):

> DE DÍA: Vaquero ninja amante del rock alternativo en Veridian Dynamics.
>
> DE NOCHE: Escribo sobre codificación y derechos de codificación para penalcoders.example.org, una fantástica organización sin fines de lucro que te quitará tu dinero ni bien ingreses a ese vínculo. Mis hijos son más bonitos que los tuyos.
>
> POR DIVERSIÓN: Chistes sobre C+, competencias de transportador Segway, crucigramas de los domingos del NYT (¡Con marcador permanente!), aseo de avestruces.
>
> "Si ves algo que te causa miedo, busca a las personas solidarias, siempre las verás ayudando". -Fred Rogers

Quizás se podría poner eso, o inventar algo nuevo, como la info de *[eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion?tab=profile)*.

Comment: Gracias ArtEze. Lo de eferion me parece interesante pero para ser usado de ejemplo en *Acerca de mí* debería proponerlo  él mismo.