# Los problemas, hallazgos e iniciativas actuales de la comunidad

Tags: discusión, sitios-internacionales

¿Recuerdas cómo empezaste a programar? Apostaría a que fue cuando muchos de ustedes eran niños que jugaban con editores gráficos después de la escuela y en algún momento decidieron averiguar cuál era la diferencia entre los archivos .img y .exe. 
Como resultado, instalaron Turbo Pascal y, en lugar de trabajar con imágenes divertidas, intentaron agregar algo al "Hola Mundo" descargado. El enfoque de programación típico en esa etapa se veía así: "¿Cómo aumentar un contador? - Copiar la línea con el contador unas cuantas veces! " Los hallazgos como funciones o un depurador no eran menos importantes que la Teoría de la Relatividad.

Además, ¿recuerdas cuando hiciste el mayor progreso? Probablemente, cuando conociste a un compañero tan interesado en la programación como tú. Es probable que durante el primer mes de trabajar juntos, tu conocimiento haya aumentado más que en el año anterior, cuando habías estudiado solo programación.

Parece que nuestras comunidades internacionales están creciendo y siguiendo el mismo escenario. Considera esto:

- Todas las comunidades internacionales comienzan con configuraciones estándar en el sitio.
- Cada comunidad enfrenta problemas similares que otras comunidades internacionales enfrentan en algún momento.
- En algún momento, algunos de los problemas se vuelven críticos.
- La comunidad, después de aportar mucho tiempo y esfuerzo, encuentra soluciones a los problemas críticos uno por uno.
- Todas las demás comunidades internacionales no se benefician de esas soluciones porque no saben lo que sucede en otros sitios y ...
- ... continúan sufriendo, hasta que los mismos problemas se vuelven muy críticos en sus sitios también.

¿Por qué no trabajar juntos?

## El problema

Las comunidades internacionales enfrentan los mismos problemas una y otra vez, pero al estar aisladas, no saben que sus problemas a menudo se han resuelto en otros lugares.

### Dos ejemplos

#### (1) Configuración del sitio

En algún momento, en Stack Overflow en ruso habíamos recibido muchas preguntas con saludos. Algunos usuarios comenzaron a editar las preguntas, lo que resultó en un gran número de ediciones en la cola de revisión. Los revisores se enojaron con los editores y la comunidad comenzó a discutir qué hacer con estas ediciones, si era necesario editar las preguntas antiguas, etc. Comenzamos a indagar y resultó que en el sitio hay una configuración que configura el motor para eliminar saludos automáticamente cuando se publica una pregunta. La misma historia fue con los comentarios similares a “gracias”.

#### (2) Iniciativas

La compañía está mejorando constantemente el sitio, incluida la interfaz de usuario. A veces esto lleva a una pérdida en la traducción. La situación es muy molesta y todas las comunidades internacionales la sufrieron hasta que [g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4?tab=profile) creó [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/), lo que ayuda a evitar la pérdida de traducciones en los casos más comunes. Desafortunadamente, traducir.win no es utilizado por todas las comunidades, lo que hace que algunas comunidades sigan perdiendo traducciones.

## Solución propuesta

Creo que las comunidades internacionales pueden ser más efectivas si avanzamos juntos. El primer paso hacia el desarrollo conjunto es comenzar a compartir nuestros problemas, hallazgos e iniciativas con todas las comunidades internacionales.

#### La esencia del enfoque.

En el contexto "[Comentarios e iniciativas sobre sitios internacionales](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/274323)", sería genial mantener una lista de los problemas actuales de cada comunidad, hallazgos (también conocidos como "problemas resueltos”) e iniciativas sobre MSE.

Por ejemplo, en la siguiente forma:

#### Iniciativas

- *traducir.win*

  - Es: [Traduciendo el sitio… Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/10).
  - Ja: [サ イ ト Traducir Traducir Traducir: traducir](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2750/78).
- *Asociaciones de preguntas*

  - Ru: [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)

#### hallazgos

- *[Eliminando saludos automáticamente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/274323)*

  - [Should the word “hay” not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially on Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996)
  - [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125)
  - Ru: [Автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/6)
- *Eliminar automáticamente un comentario cuando un usuario lo marca como que ya no es necesario*

  - Ru: [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6).

#### Problemas actuales

- *¡Añade un problema que molesta a tu comunidad aquí!*

---

Si tenes alguna idea sobre la iniciativa, ¡compártela!

Al mismo tiempo, no duden en agregar los problemas, hallazgos e iniciativas actuales de su comunidad a la lista. Incluso si cambiamos el proceso en función de los comentarios, la lista nos ayudará a ver la situación real.

### Nota del traductor.

En nuestro caso, seria ideal agregar lo que pensemos que necesitamos informar directamente en el post original.

El original es:

[Your community’s current problems, findings, and initiatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/141717)