# La Terminal: Un medio de discutir para usuarios internacionales

Tags: discusión, chat, sitios-internacionales

> Versión original en inglés en MSE:
>   [The Terminal: a chat room for international site users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317209/the-terminal-a-chat-room-for-international-site-users)
>   por  Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦.

[image]

Un factor esencial de [nuestro éxito](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3693) es la comunicación efectiva. Me alegra presentar una nueva sala de chat que se llama "[The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)" ("La Terminal"). La Terminal será un medio para usuarios internacionales y cualquier otra persona que tienen fervor para nuestras comunidades. La creación de la sala de chat es para intentar mejorar:

1. *Comunicación entre comunidades*. Creo que debemos crear un medio donde las comunidades internacionales puedan [discutir sus problemas cotidianos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3711) y conocerse mutuamente en una manera rápida e informal.
2. *Comprender lo que necesitan Uds.*. La mejor manera de comprender lo que necesita una comunidad es escuchar a sus usuarios. Me parece que pierdo de lo que se hace en las metas internacionales. Si piensan que yo, como empleado, necesito ver algo en tu meta, por favor, dímelo en el chat.
3. *Ayuda puntual*. Me siento mal de que los usuarios internacional de la comunidad no puedan hablar por chat con alguien de la compañía cuando necesitan ayuda con el sitio. Mándenme un ping en la sala de chat cuando se necesita ayuda.

¡Por favor [únanse al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)! ¡Conozcan a otras personas internacionales y díganme como puedo ayudarles!

Comment: No era necesario decir que lo has traducido tú pues eres el autor original y la publicaciones cuentas con una tarjeta de usuario con tu imagen, reputación, medallas y nombre de usuario con enlace a tu perfil.

Comment: En relación a "El Terminal o La Terminal" de acuerdo a [este artículo](https://elportaldetuvoz.wordpress.com/tag/el-terminal-o-la-terminal/) "La RAE establece que se usa predominante en femenino en la mayor parte del ámbito hispánico"