# Falta traducción en Preguntas Bloqueadas

Tags: bug, traducciones

Buscando usuarios que han ganado la medalla Gurú me conseguí esta pregunta

> [Uso de Ñ en nombre de variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%c3%91-en-nombre-de-variables)

El texto aparece de la siguiente forma, en inglés:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. See the centro de ayuda for guidance on writing a good question.

dejo el enlace de [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/14157)

Comment: y no hiciste la traducción porque.... (complete el porque)

Comment: no quiero pasar como la publicidad de openenglish..... [que mal ingles wey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPljzhCplT4)

Comment: @fedorqui con la pregunta que me marcastes como duplicada usa transifex, ahora por lo que entiendo nosotros estamos usando [traducir.win](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3378/traduciendo-el-sitio-esta-vez-con-m%c3%a1s-control-sobre-el-proceso)

Comment: @JackNavaRow sí, efectivamente, pero traducir.win al fin y al cabo es una capa sobre Transifex. Más segura, más fiable, más todo.

Comment: creo que debemos de crear un meta de como reportar traducciones en el meta (parece que escribi algo recursivo xD)