# Nuevo diseño en la pagina de perfil de usuario

Tags: soporte

Hace poco vi que rediseñaron la pagina de perfil de usuario, y el diseño quedo bien, pero porque quitaron el dato que decia el tiempo de inactividad del usuario en stackoverflow, para mi esa informacion era importante. Ademas, hay que traducir al español textos que estan en ingles en ese nuevo diseño.

Comment: Cualquiera puede traducir los textos de la pagina...

Comment: @gbianchi, Como?. Pero en realidad a mi lo que me interesa es lo otro q digo, pq quitaron la inactividad del usuario en el sistema

Comment: Para traducir, hace años que tenemos un proceso estandar.. mira [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3378/traduciendo-el-sitio-esta-vez-con-más-control-sobre-el-proceso)... para lo otro, tendrias que preguntar en meta...

Comment: Lo primero se avisó en [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive).

Comment: ¿El color azul en el badge de algunos perfiles hace parte de estos cambios?