# Falta la traducción del dialog que confirma la reversión

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Al momento de revertir sale un cuadro de confirmación, el cual está en inglés.

> [image: Imagen del dialog]

No sé cómo apoyar a la traducción del sitio, pero mi sugerencia si alguien lo hace sería

> Todos los cambios después de esta revisión serán revertidos

Comment: buenas! la cadena está [acá, en traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/strings/16925). Ahí te podés loguear con tu cuenta de Stack Overflow en español y proponer la traducción. Marcala como urgente así un mod la revisa. [Acá podés leer más sobre el proceso de traducción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272)