# Moviendo Traducir a la infraestructura de Stack Overflow

Tags: discusión, traducciones, anuncios, sitios-internacionales

Hace ya mucho tiempo desde que [empezamos a usar Traducir en Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272) en 2018. Lo hicimos open source, lo que no sólo nos permitió que mucha gente colaborara, también fue una forma de discutir ideas e implementaciones.

Algo interesante de Traducir es que fue la misma comunidad de usuarios internacionales la que resolvió el problema de las traducciones de forma autogestionada, construyendo las herramientas nosotros mismos.

A nivel de esfuerzo, fue mucho tiempo en 2018 ideando la solución e implementándola. Pero a partir de ahí, lo único "grande" fue la reescritura del frontend para dejar de usar React. Fuera de eso, es una app que simplemente funciona. Incluso compartirlo con los otros sitios internacionales fue relativamente sencillo (hoy en día, todas las comunidades internacionales lo usan para manejar su traducciones).

Mirando el gráfico de commits, me enorgullece el hecho de haber construido juntos una herramienta súper util que requiere tan poco mantenimiento:

[image: Gráfico de GitHub mostrando los commits al proyecto Traducir]

Desde el primer día, Traducir corre en mi infraestructura. Originalmente no era mucho problema (ya que las traducciones eran revisadas por un CM antes de ser aplicadas). Pero una vez que se automatizó ese proceso, la verdad es que estoy un poco nervioso por ser responsable de mantener mis servidores seguros (me considero un buen desarrollador, pero un mediocre SRE).

Cuando me fui de Stack Overflow la primera vez, transferí el dominio a la empresa, pero seguí corriendo todo en mi infraestructura. Ahora que me voy de Stack Overflow de vuelta (el 26 de Abril de 2023 es mi último día), me encantaría dejar esta responsabilidad dentro de la empresa.

Es por esto que estamos planeando mover Traducir a la infrastructura de Stack Overflow, donde la empresa se va a encargar de su mantenimiento y de su seguridad.

Como parte de este plan, vamos a:

1. Hacer un fork [del proyecto público](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) a la organización privada de Stack Overflow en GitHub
2. Archivar el repositorio público (así el código puede seguir siendo consultado, pero dejando claro que no es el código que corre en producción)
3. Mover la aplicación a la infraestructura de Stack Overflow

Esto implica que la comunidad no va a poder abrir PRs para arreglar bugs o implementar nuevas funcionalidades, pero cuando miramos la historia de contribuciones, nos encontramos con que la última contribución significativa de un no empleado fue en el 2019 (y fue konamiman, ex-empleado) por lo que no parece que sea una pérdida significativa. Esto no va a cambiar cómo la comunidad usa Traducir para traducir el sitio (excepto por unos minutos de downtime cuando hacemos la migración), pero quería asegurarme de que la comunidad conociera el plan.

Así que esa es la noticia, sacarme este peso de la espalda y pasárselo a Stack Overflow es algo que me da mucha tranquilidad :) Si tienen comentarios o preguntas, déjenlas acá. Y si encuentran problemas usando Traducir (o quieren proponer mejoras), las pueden postear en Meta (y los moderadores del sitio las pueden [escalar a los empleados](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/238921) si es necesario).

Comment: Esto a sido una de las mejores cosas que hemos hecho como comunidad para SO... mas allá de mis pocos commits, estoy orgulloso de haber ayudado con esto. Lo único que me apena, es que no siga siendo público. Pero supongo en algún momento eso se podrá solucionar, ya que en si no tiene nada que ver con el código de SO.

Comment: A mi también me apena... pero sin dudas analizar el movimiento que ha tenido últimamente me hace sentir mejor

Comment: muchas gracias por la herramienta, de verdad que fue y es un aporte incalculable para las comunidades, me pregunto si esto es aplicable a cualquier proyecto incluso fuera de las redes de SE ... por que no convertirlo en un proyecto publico para facilitar las traducciones de otros proyectos ... etc ... @g3rv4