# Al ir a cerrar una pregunta sale en inglés "Closing", "votes remaining" y "vote to close"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Al ir a cerrar una pregunta, hay tres cadenas que aparecen en inglés:

- Closing
- votes remaining
- vote to close

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ambas ya están en Transifex y fueron traducidas hace tiempo, por lo que tiene toda la pinta de ser un contenido nuevo que está hardcodeado.

Se ha reportado lo mismo sobre SOru: [Translations are not used from Transifex for localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306244/209901)

Comment: Ultimamente hay muchos casos de textos que estaban bien traducidos y están de nuevo en inglés ... :/

Comment: @lois6b sí, al parecer, un leve cambio en el texto original hace que a Transifex ya le conste como nuevo. ([referencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3076/83)).

Comment: Pero el hecho que el texto aparezca como traducido hace pensar en algo _hardcodeado_.

Comment: La cadena está traducida... y no ha sido cambiada en un buen tiempo... sin embargo, el pull no la trae (porque ya está en la BD). Lo que puedo ofrecer es mirarlo después del trabajo.

Comment: @g3rv4 curioso... Está [reportado en Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306244/209901), por lo que entiendo que algún desarrollador de core puede mirarlo en horario de trabajo, jeje. Pero, evidentemente, si lo puedes investigar te lo agradeceremos un montón.

Comment: genial, si está en meta.se va a ir por los caminos habituales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miré y miré y miré y no encontré nada... el código donde aparecen estos textos no ha sido modificado desde hace más de 4 años, por lo que no se trata de una [destraducción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3031/11272).

Recién hicimos un build y comprobé en SOpt y SOru que está solucionado. No hay mensajes de error en el build anterior. Ya avisé esto en el chat de core, si esto vuelve a pasar lo miramos con más detenimiento.

Comment: Curioso... Adam Lear y Samo (no sé quién es este/a último/a) mencionan que [no pueden reproducir el error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306244/translations-are-not-used-from-transifex-for-localized-sites#comment995612_306244).

Answer (score 1):

Esto se ha resuelto ya en todos los sitios internacionales.  Estamos investigando la razón por el cambio pero por ahora, no veremos mas problemas con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]